# When you have two variables as input

Tags: python

I came across these lines of code in machine learning using python.

```
z = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
# Compute sigmoid  Activation function
A_sigmoid, z = sigmoid(z)
```

Please, what is line three saying? Basically, I want to know how to separate 2  inputs with a comma on the lefthand side. A_sigmoid was never predefined.

Thank you.

```
z = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
# Compute sigmoid  Activation function
A_sigmoid, z = sigmoid(z)
```

Comment: It is _unpacking_ a tuple response into individual names. That _is_ the definition of `A_sigmoid` (in terms of defining it in your code, not that that name or this particular example is special in any way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> t = (1, 2)  # define a tuple
>>> a, b = t  # unpack it
>>> print(a)
1
>>> print(b)
2
```

Note that `a,b = t` where `t = (1, 2)` is the same as doing `(a, b) = (1, 2)`.